# Best way to store 256 bit AVX vectors into unsigned long integers

Tags: c, vector, avx, avx2, avx512

I was wondering what is the best way to store a 256 bit long AVX vectors into 4 64 bit unsigned long integers. According to the functions written in the website https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ I could only figure out using maskstore(code below) to do this. But is it the best way to do so? Or there exist other methods for this?

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned long long int i,j;
    unsigned long long int bit[32][4];//256 bit random numbers
    unsigned long long int bit_out[32][4];//256 bit random numbers for test

    for(i=0;i<32;i++){ //load with 64 bit random integers
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            bit[i][j]=rand();
            bit[i][j]=bit[i][j]<<32 | rand();
        }
    }

//--------------------load masking-------------------------
    __m256i v_bit[32];
    __m256i mask;
    unsigned long long int mask_ar[4];
    mask_ar[0]=~(0UL);mask_ar[1]=~(0UL);mask_ar[2]=~(0UL);mask_ar[3]=~(0UL);
    mask = _mm256_loadu_si256 ((__m256i const *)mask_ar);
//--------------------load masking ends-------------------------

//--------------------------load the vectors-------------------
    for(i=0;i<32;i++){

        v_bit[i]=_mm256_loadu_si256 ((__m256i const *)bit[i]);

    }
//--------------------------load the vectors ends-------------------

//--------------------------extract from the vectors-------------------
    for(i=0;i<32;i++){

        _mm256_maskstore_epi64 (bit_out[i], mask, v_bit[i]);
    }
//--------------------------extract from the vectors end-------------------

    for(i=0;i<32;i++){ //load with 64 bit random integers
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(bit[i][j]!=bit_out[i][j])
                printf("----ERROR----\n");
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best way is not to. `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to have 64 bits. If you need a specific bitwidth (and encoding), use fixed-width types from `stdint.h`.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the `extract`, `set` and `insert` intrinsics. I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Christoph I just want to extract 256 vector in in 4, 64 bit integers. I didn't find the intrinsics you mentioned in the above mentioned page.

Comment: If the destination 64 bit ints are contiguous then just use `_mm256_storeu_si256`.

Comment: In C11, use `_Alignas(32)  unsigned long long int bit[32][4];` to get the compiler to align the stack memory for your array.  This helps with performance even if you still use `_mm256_storeu_ps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other said in comments you do not need to use mask store in this case. the following loop got no error in your program

```
for(i=0;i<32;i++){
   _mm256_storeu_si256 ((__m256i const *) bit_out[i], v_bit[i]);

}
```

So the best instruction that you are looking for is `_mm256_storeu_si256` this instruction stores a `__m256i` vector to unaligned address if your data are aligned you can use `_mm256_store_si256`. to see your vectors values you can use this function:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
alignas(32) unsigned long long int tempu64[4];
void printVecu64(__m256i vec)
{
    _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)&tempu64[0], vec);
    printf("[0]= %u, [1]=%u, [2]=%u, [3]=%u \n\n", tempu64[0],tempu64[1],tempu64[2],tempu64[3]) ;

}
```

the  `_mm256_maskstore_epi64` let you choose the elements that you are going to store to the memory. This instruction is useful when you want to store a vector with more options to store an element to the memory or not change the memory value.

I was reading the **Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual (248966-032), 2016, page 410.** and interestingly found out that unaligned store is still a performance killer.

> **11.6.3 Prefer Aligned Stores Over Aligned Loads**
>
> There are cases where it is possible to align only a subset of the
> processed data buffers. In these cases, aligning data buffers used for
> store operations usually yields better performance than aligning data
> buffers used for load operations. Unaligned stores are likely to cause
> greater performance degradation than unaligned loads, since there is a
> very high penalty on stores to a split cache-line that crosses pages.
> This penalty is estimated at **150 cycles**. Loads that cross a page
> boundary are executed at retirement. In Example 11-12, unaligned store
> address can affect SAXPY performance for 3 unaligned addresses to
> about one quarter of the aligned case.

I shared here because some people said there are no differences between aligned/unaligned store except in debuging!

Comment: `_mm256_store_si256` has no advantage over `_mm256_storeu_si256` except maybe for debugging if you expect memory to be aligned and it's not then `_mm256_store_si256` would crash your code.

Comment: @Zboson sadly ICC emits a unaligned load even if you use `_mm256_store_si256`. This has caused me some grey hairs when the code suddenly crashed with other compilers.

Comment: @Christoph, i should have said the instructions instead of the intrinsics but using another compiler can also be a way useful for debugging.

Comment: Fun fact: Skylake vastly reduces the 4k-split penalty, down to barely more than the cache-line split penalty.  (I think this is correct for stores as well as loads).

Comment: yes, I never experiences penalties for unaligned loads in SKL. But, processor vendors are some killers...

Comment: Update on this: `_mm256_storeu_si256` vs. `_mm256_store_si256` can make your code slower with GCC, even if your data is aligned.  [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726).  If your data is aligned, there's no downside to using unaligned load/store *instructions* on any CPU that supports AVX, but GCC with some tuning options will split unaligned 256-bit loads and/or stores into `vmovups xmm` / `vextractf128` (not a single insn), hurting performance on aligned arrays.  That's avoided on Intel Haswell and later by using `-march=native`